# Where is the documentation for SQL Server's blocked process report?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, sql-server-2019, blocking

I'm trying to work with the blocked process reports captured using Extended Events and, while I can find numerous blog articles and Q&A about specific details (e.g.[1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/) [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205528/dba-blocking-query-email-alert) [3](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/building-custom-blocked-process-report/)), I can't find any documentation from MS about the contents of the report & how to interpret each field.

For example, I'd like to know:

- What are `clientoption1`and `clientoption2`
- Why do I sometimes get an `object_id` that doesn't exist in my database ([like this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a63e2efb-e520-4550-a72f-ecde7e72e8be/extended-events-blockedprocessreport-objectid-and-indexid-incorrect?forum=sqlkjmanageability))
- What does `index_id` indicate (probably answered at link above)
- How to decode `waitresource` ([here's a start](https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/17/decoding-key-and-page-waitresource-for-deadlocks-and-blocking/))
- ... and the list goes on.

I don't just want answers to these questions, I want something more complete.

Is this an undocumented feature or am I just crap at finding it?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238982/blocked-process-report / https://michaeljswart.com/2011/04/a-new-way-to-examine-blocked-process-reports/ might be useful resources

Comment: Thanks, yes I've found those helpful. But still, nothing comprehensive from MS.

Comment: If you only want something from MS, you might want to contact MS.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping for something comprehensive and well-structured, no you're right it needn't be from MS. Most of the articles and answers I find are quite narrowly focused or just a poor rewrite of someone else's post. Many are also really old, so possibly superseded by better ways of doing things.

Comment: Better ways of doing things with the blocked process report that hasn't changed since 2005? Meh, I doubt it.

Comment: Perhaps the contents haven't changed (how is one supposed to know when there's no documentation and you're learning about it for the first time), but ways of working with it certainly have ... for example Michael's blog post that you linked to is out of date and doesn't mention supporting Extended Events (although the github project does).

Comment: Sure, blog posts are not going to be kept up to date forever. Can you imagine how many blog posts talk about splitting or aggregating strings but were written before `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` were introduced? I probably have at least a dozen myself. Am I going to go back and rewrite them all? Fat chance. People can still learn from them but if they're not finding newer approaches from myself and others there's not much as an author I'm able to do about that.

Comment: Also, you saw in Michael's article [this link](https://github.com/mjswart/sqlblockedprocesses), right, where he does have XE support?

Answer (score 0):

fwiw (which isn't much), [I asked MS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/3148) about this and they filed it under "sure, we'll do that later", recommending these docs for now:

- [Blocked Process Report Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15) - describes the event class (I think the article is talking about traces not extended events, but presumably it's still relevant), but doesn't give info about the xml report contents.
- [Understand and resolve SQL Server blocking problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/understand-resolve-blocking) - quite a comprehensive article but unfortunately doesn't talk about the contents of the blocked_process_report.
- [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#deadlock_xevent) addresses the xml_deadlock_report Extended Event for deadlock reports. That's not for blocked process reports but it looks like some of the fields that are documented are the same

Answer (score 0):

Does this linke help you at all?
https://manualzz.com/doc/25790559/sql-server-event-class-reference---microsoft-docs help?

Blocked Process Report Event Class in particular.

Comment: Not sure, it’s 702 pages long :-) Which bit?

Comment: From the table of contents, I followed Blocked Process Report Event Class which took me to: https://manualzz.com/viewer_next/web/manual?file=%2F%2Fs3p.manualzz.com%2Fstore%2Fdata%2F025790559.pdf%3Fk%3DAwAAAXyUO84UAAACWETh-Y8jTAQcCLIbegdtxJilafzJ&img=%2F%2Fs3.manualzz.com%2Fstore%2Fdata%2F025790559_1-eddc974a30fabc00078432a484dea44f&ads=true#file%3A///W%3A/gdoj-o-8ec83091/sql/.tmp/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/175277)